# Identity Server 4 ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC unable to render JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, .net-core-3.1

I have an Identity Server 4 with an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project and would like to add an external script into the `_Layout.cshtml` file. The JS file is being ran, however it is not working as expected. I believe this has to do with Identity Server 4 unable to parse the function or I am missing an ASP.NET Core MVC package.

Markup is supposed to be injected into the widget div via main.js script.

```
<body>
    <div id="widget"></div>
    <script src="~/js/main.js?v=@Guid.NewGuid()"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Note: The script works fine if I pull down this project https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio-code and insert the script into this `_Layout.cshtml`, I am able to see that it is working as expected.

The main difference being in .csproj -
`<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`
vs
`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`

But I don't know if that matters.
Please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Can you pls add how the script is rendered by opening devtools (F12) in the browser, go to the Elements inspector, and copying the rendered scripttag

Comment: This is how it's rendered in the elements tab - <script src="/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -- and when I right click on "/js/main.js" and select reveal in sources panel, it takes me to the source code of main.js, so it is coming back and being hit. @Pieterjan